# Binding dynamic elements to a function; left with only one bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

My config (as an example) is setup like so:

```
this.config = [
    {
        element: '#Amount',
        type: "money",
        notNull: true,
        error: "You must specify an amount"
    },
    {
        element: '#Type',
        type: "string",
        notNull: true,
        error: "You must specify whether you want a 6 week loan or a 12 month loan"
    }
]
```

I have a bind function that should bind a validation function to each element in the list:

```
this.bind = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < _this.config.length; i++) {
        var arr = _this.config[i];
        console.log('Binding ' + arr.element + ' to single input validation')
        // bind single validation to each element
        $(document).on('keyup', arr.element, function () {
            _this.validate(arr.element)
        })
    }
}
```

And in the console I am presented with:

```
Binding #Amount to single input validation
Binding #Type to single input validation
Binding #LoanPurpose to single input validation
```

The config actually consists of 47 elements, however I am certain that only the last bind remains after iterating through the config so it's as if it's replacing the previous bind each time.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic javascript error. Your nested `keyup` handler function references a variable `arr`, which is getting overwritten by the `for` loop every iteration. So when the `keyup` handler finally does execute, it's using the `arr` that is referencing the last element in `this.config` array.

This link explains [why it's bad to make functions within loops](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop).  And provides a solution for it.

Here's how your code should probably look:

```
this.bind = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < _this.config.length; i++) {
        var arr = _this.config[i];
        console.log('Binding ' + arr.element + ' to single input validation')
        // bind single validation to each element
        _this.makeBind(arr.element)
    }
}

this.makeBind = function (el) {
    $(document).on('blur', el, function () {
        _this.validate(el)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config.forEach(function(item) {
  $(document.body).on('keyup', item.element, function() {
    validate(item, this.value)
  });
});
```

You can do something like the preceding to pass both the item, and the input's current value to the validate function